# Turn handdrawn doodles into graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing

I have doodled sketches of graphs in JPG format (they roughly look like stick men, in particular the vertices are not shown - they should be where the lines meet) and want to convert them into proper graphs in Mathematica.

Note that I am not concerned about the direction of edges, the graph structure is what matters, not the orientation of the edges or their coordinates; as long as I get a graph that's isomorphic to the sketched graph, that would be fine for me).

What can I do? Any help is welcome! TIA!

---

This is an example of a sketch that I want Mathematica to turn into a graph

[image: example]

When the sketches are a bit more rough with thicker edges, then kglr's (original) approach does not seem to work. I attached another figure. Note that this at first was ONLY the lines with a blank interior. I actually used a paint program to fill the inner part with black, but it did not work accurately, which makes everything more difficult, I guess. Is there anything I can do about this?

[image: example2]

Comment: `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 8},
 PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled",
 GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]`

Answer (score 11):

```
doodle = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJcLR.jpg"]
```

[image]

```
mg = MorphologicalGraph @ ColorReplace[doodle, {White -> Black, Black -> White}]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[mg]
```

> [image]

```
Graph[mg, PlotTheme -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

[image]

```
doodle2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRyDA.png"]
```

[image]

```
mg2 = MorphologicalGraph@
  SkeletonTransform @ Thinning @
    Closing[ColorNegate @ Binarize @ doodle2, DiskMatrix[2]]
```

[image]

```
Graph[mg2, PlotTheme -> "VintageDiagram"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Before using MorphologicalGraph with your image that has thick lines, try thinning, after filling in the noise in your image:

```
Thinning[FillingTransform[ColorNegate[Binarize[image]]]]
```

If that leaves a few short edges you don't want, try the Pruning function.